# ruby include, dynamic letters and symbols

Tags: ruby, parsing

Say I build an array like this:

```
:001 > holder = "This.File.Q99P84.Is.Awesome"
=> "This.File.Q99P84.Is.Awesome" 
:002 > name = holder.split(".")
=> ["This", "File", "Q99P84", "Is", "Awesome"]
```

Now, I can do:

```
name[2].include? 'Q99P84'
```

Instead of putting in 'Q99P84' I want to put in something like 'symbol for Q followed by
symbol for number, symbol for number, symbol for P, symbol for number, symbol for number
so the .include? function will be dynamic. So any file name I load that has Q##P## will return `true`.

I'm pretty sure this is possibly I just don't know exactly what to search. If you know the answer can you link me to the documentation.

Comment: this is called "regular expressions". Try to google them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is through Regular Expressions ('regex' for short). Two good sources of information is [Regular Expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) which is more Ruby centric.

One way to use regex on a string is the [`String#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-match) method:

```
names[2].match(/Q\d\dP\d\d/) # /d stands for digit
```

This will return the string if there is a match and it will return `nil` if there isn't.

```
"Q42P67".match(/Q\d\dP\d\d/) #=> "Q42P67"
"H33P55".match(/Q\d\dP\d\d/) #=> nil
```

This is helpful in an `if` condition since a returned string is 'truthy' and `nil` is 'falsely'.

```
names[2] = "Q42P67"
if names[2].match(/Q\d\dP\d\d/)
   # Will execute code here
end

names[2] = "H33P55"
if names[2].match(/Q\d\dP\d\d/)
   # Will not execute code here
end
```

I hope that helps until you dig further into your study of Regular Expressions.

**EDIT:**
Note that the Q and P in `/Q\d\dP\d\d/` are capital letters. If case is not important, you can append an 'i' for case-insensitivity. `/Q\d\dP\d\d/i` will capture "Q42P67" and "q42P67"

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is regular expression matching. The Ruby [regexp object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) will help you. What you want is something like

```
/Q[\d+]P[\d+]/.match(name[2])
```

...which will return a truthy value if `name[2]` has a string which matches a character `Q`, one or more digits (0-9), a character `P`, then one or more digits. This is probably too flexible a match if the pattern you want has exactly two digits in those number spaces; for that you might try a more specific pattern:

```
/Q\d\dP\d\d/.match(name[2])
```